# Magento 2 MageSpecialist reCAPTCHA Module display on cms page

Tags: magento, magento2

I've installed the [MageSpecialist reCAPTCHA](https://github.com/magento/magespecialist_ReCaptcha) module on my Magento 2 webshop.

The module is working perfectly fine on the default contact form, but the reCAPTCHA is not rendered on the custom cms page.

This is how I display the contact form on the custom cms page:

`{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}`

I tried to add a code snippet from the layout section of the module contact_index_index to the cms page Layout Update XML.

```
<referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="MSP\ReCaptcha\Block\Frontend\ReCaptcha" name="msp-recaptcha" after="-" template="MSP_ReCaptcha::msp_recaptcha.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="msp-recaptcha" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">MSP_ReCaptcha/js/reCaptcha</item>
                                <item name="zone" xsi:type="string">contact</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

This also did not help with trying to render the reCAPTCHA on the custom cms page.

Is there anyone who can help me out with this?

Comment: try to use referenceContainer name="content" on cms page Layout Update XML

Comment: @faizanbeg Thanks for the response! Doing this indeed made the reCAPTCHA appear, now I just need to put it inside the form. I also tried "contactForm" as reference. It did not help, but reCAPTCHA was still visible. Do you have other ideas?

Comment: you have to assign recapcha as a child of contact form then it will appear inside contact form

Answer (score 3):

With the below code I was able to add Contact Us form in a CMS page along with the MSP reCaptcha on the form, Add the below code in Admin > Content > Pages > [CMS Page] > Add / Edit > Design > Layout Update XML:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
<block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml">
<container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
</block>
</referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
        <block class="MSP\ReCaptcha\Block\Frontend\ReCaptcha" name="msp-recaptcha" after="-"
               template="MSP_ReCaptcha::msp_recaptcha.phtml">

            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="msp-recaptcha" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">MSP_ReCaptcha/js/reCaptcha</item>
                            <item name="zone" xsi:type="string">contact</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```